# Deleting-Updating a dataview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need your help PLEASE!
I have a table: tblCustomer. (serial,Name,Email,Address)

I did the following:
insert-update-delete in dataset(that contains the table tblCustomer)

What I need to do, and I need your help in it, is:
insert-update-delete in dataview.
I tried to do the following:

```
 Dim dv As New DataView(_DataSet.Tables(0))
        ' select deleted rows 
        dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.Deleted
        For _irow As Long = 0 To dv.Table.Rows.Count - 1
            ' if serial is null, that means the row is new and deleted 
            ' so no need to add it to database 
            If Not IsDBNull(dv!serial) Then
                ' delete row from database 
                Dim _SQL As String = "DELETE FROM tblCustomer WHERE Serial = " & dv!serial.ToString
                ' open the connection and execute the delete command 
                Dim strconnection As String = "Data Source=EASMAR-PC;Initial Catalog=Database Connection;Integrated Security=True;"
                Dim _cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strconnection)
                _cn.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from tblCustomer where serial= '" & txtSerial.Text & "'"

            End If
        Next
```

I am getting this error: `Conversion from string "serial" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`
On this line: `If Not IsDBNull(dv!serial) Then`
And the same error on: `Dim _SQL As String = "DELETE FROM tblCustomer WHERE Serial = " & dv!serial.ToString`

Can you help me PLEASE.
Thank you.

Comment: no need to repeat PLEASE and HELP so many times, we'll do what we can anyway

Answer (score 0):

what type is `serial`? `Integer` I guess, from the error. Plus it seems you're passing the literal string value "serial" instead of a number.

Also, in your two `DELETE` statements you're passing it both **WITH** and **WITHOUT** `' '`. 
remove those `' '`.

And what's that _SQL string variable? you're not using it.

Try:

```
If Not IsDBNull(dv!serial) Then
    ' open the connection and execute the delete command 
    Dim strconnection As String = "Data Source=EASMAR-PC;Initial Catalog=Database Connection;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim _cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strconnection)
    _cn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "Delete from tblCustomer where serial= " & txtSerial.Text
End If
```

Comment: serial is autoincremented.It's the primary key

Comment: @user2968155 so you surely don't want to pass a `'` character in your SQL query.

Comment: I am still getting this error: `Conversion from string "serial" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`
On this line:`If Not IsDBNull(dv!serial) Then`

Comment: I am hovering the mouse over it, but i'm not getting anything :/

Comment: @user2968155 I don't think you understand what this site is about, you keep asking questions and never accept an answer. This site is to provide help, not debugging your complete application because you don't have time to do it.